# How to use lookup tables as .tx in Rasa?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

In my nlu.yml file I have my code as:

```
- lookup: project
  project.txt
```

My project.txt file in in under data and so is my nlu.yml file.
I'm getting the exception as yaml syntax exception, could not find expectated ':'
Could someone help me out? Where should I put that colon?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert `project.txt` to `yml` format.

This [answer](https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-provide-the-lookup-entities-in-txt-format/4518/20) should help you.